# C++ (Korean) insert error (Incorrect string value)

Tags: c++, mysql, database, insert

> DB is a C ++ in conjunction with student card management program.
>   Enter your information to receive a student receives a first input your name and ID. The problem is that there is an error in the insert names.

---

When directly from MS-DOS window insert (visual studio X)
Hangul (korean) is normal.

(Try the workaround that looked out to the Internet.)

---

[image: normal korean]

when the insert through a C ++, Hangul (Korean) is not.

---

hakbun int(50) not null primary key,
name char(100) not null

▲ columns of the table, including information

---

[image: table info]

▲ query status

> Source Code

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "winsock2.h"
#include "mysql.h"
#include "tchar.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
#pragma comment (lib, "libmysql.lib")

const char * host = "localhost";
const char * user = "root";
const char * pw = "1234";
const char * db = "point_db";
void DBconnect () {

 MYSQL * connection = NULL, conn;
 MYSQL_RES * sql_result;
 MYSQL_ROW sql_row;

 mysql_init (& conn);
 connection = mysql_real_connect (& conn, host, user, pw, db, 3306, (char *) NULL, 0);
 if (connection == NULL) {
  printf ( "con error");
 }

 // Mysql_query (connection, "set session character_set_connection = utf-8;");
 // Mysql_query (connection, "set session character_set_results = utf-8;");
 // Mysql_query (connection, "set session character_set_client = utf-8;");
}

int _tmain (int argc, _TCHAR * argv []) {
 
 MYSQL * connection = NULL;
 MYSQL conn;
 MYSQL_RES * sql_result;
 MYSQL_ROW sql_row;

 if (mysql_init (& conn) == NULL) {
  printf ( "mysql_init () error!");
 }

 connection = mysql_real_connect (& conn, host, user, pw, db, 3306, (const char *) NULL, 0);
 if (connection == NULL) {
  printf ( "% d Error:% s,% d \ n", mysql_errno (& conn), mysql_error (& conn));
  return 1;
 }
 else {
  DBconnect ();

  int query_stat;
  char query [1024];
  char num;

  while (1) {

   cout << "+ -------------------- +" << endl;
   cout << "| ① create card |" << Endl;
   cout << "+ -------------------- +" << endl;
   cout << "Enter Number (Played: 0)>";
   cin >> num;

   switch (num) {

   case '1':

    int i, hakbun, student;
    char name [100];

    cout << "student number";
    cin >> hakbun;
    cout << "name";
    cin >> name;

    // Insert
    sprintf_s (query, "insert into point (hakbun, name) values ​​( '% d', '% s')", hakbun, name);

    query_stat = mysql_query (connection, query);
    if (query_stat! = 0) {
     printf ( "error:% s", mysql_error (& conn));
     return 1;
    }
    else {
     cout << "you have completed the creation card." << Endl;
    }

   default:
    cout << "to end the program." << Endl;
    exit (0);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

> my.ini file Detail

```
[mysqld]

basedir = C:/mysql-5.7.15-winx64
datadir = C:/mysql-5.7.15-winx64/data
port = 3306
# server_id = .....

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

#add
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
init_connect=”SET collation_connection = utf8_general_ci”
init_connect=”SET NAMES utf8″
character-set-server = utf8
[client]
default-character-set = utf8
[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8
[mysqldump]
default-character-set = utf8
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using the low-level MySQL driver you will have to be extremely careful when it comes to inserting values and ensure you've properly escaped everything or you'll have nasty [SQL injection holes](http://bobby-tables.com). If you can find anything that gives you a layer of abstraction here, anything at all, it's probably better than what you're doing here with the C API.

Comment: Where do I see the C API?

Comment: If you search for "mysql c api" you [get this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api.html). I'm not sure how you got this far without reading the documentation. Tutorials and examples are never enough.